# PHP script returns success but does not save a new row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a PHP script that gets an audio file with additional information which will be uploaded on my server and inserts the new data in my MySQL database as a new row.

Uploading the file on my server works and my script returns a success (true for execute()) when the SQL Query insert has been done. However, I will not find the new data in my database.

I tried a couple of things and I know it had worked already some time ago... but for some reason nothing happens anymore to my database.

**My PHP script**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


require 'PostAudio_dbconnection.php';

$title = $_REQUEST['audioTitle'];
$user = $_REQUEST['audioAuthor'];
$language = $_REQUEST['audioLanguage'];
$playlist = $_REQUEST['audioPlaylist'];
$description = $_REQUEST['audioDescription'];
$genre = $_REQUEST['audioGenre'];

$response = array();

$target_dir = "uploads/" . $user . "/audios" . "/" . $playlist . "/" ;

 
if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){             
   
    switch($_GET['apicall']) {

        case 'upload':

            
            $message = "Params";
            $is_error = false;

            if(!isset($_POST['audioDescription'])){
                $is_error = true;
                $message .= " desc, "; 
                
            }

            
            if(!isset($_FILES['audio']['name'])){
                $is_error = true;
                $message .= "audio is required";
            }

            if(!isset($_FILES['audio']['name'])){
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = $message;
            } else {
                
                
                $target_file = $target_dir .  $title . '.' . pathinfo($_FILES['audio']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $third = $target_dir .  $_FILES['audio']['name'];
                $anothertry =  basename($_FILES["audio"]["name"]);
                
                
                

                

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'], "$target_dir/$anothertry")){

                

                    
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO AllAudios (`title`,`author`,`language`,`playlist`, `description`,`path`,`genre`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                    
                    

                    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                        echo "\n jungää";
                    } else {
                        
                        #$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", "an audio", "an author", "denglish", "Weekend",  $_POST['desc'], $target_file, "Funny");
           
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", strval($title), strval($user), strval($language), strval($playlist),  strval($description), strval($target_dir), strval($genre));
                    }
                    
                    if($stmt->execute()){
                    
                        
                        $response['error'] = false;
                        $response['message'] = "Audio uploaded successfully";
                        $response['audio'] = getBaseURL() . $target_file;
                        $response['title'] = $title;
                        $response['playlist'] = $playlist;
                        $response['genre'] = $genre;
                        $response['description'] = $description;

                        mysqli_close($conn);
                    } else {
                        
                        //echo gettype(strval($playlist));
                        $response['error'] = true;
                        $response['message'] = "Try afain öater...";

                    }

                } else {
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "Try again later...";
                    $response['playlist'] = $playlist;
                    $response['joja'] = $target_dir;
                    $response['cur'] = $_FILES['audio']['name'];
                }
            
            }

break;
```

**My PHP connection script**

```
<?php

$db_name = "AudioUploads";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "DataBaba1";
$server_name = "localhost";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection Failed :" . $conn->connect_error);
    
}
```

**My database structure**

```
# Name       Type      Collation           Attributes Null Default  Extra
1 aID        int(15)                                  No   None     AUTO_INCREMENT
2 title      text      latin1_swedish_ci              Yes  NULL
3 author     text      latin1_swedish_ci              Yes  NULL
4 language   text      latin1_swedish_ci              Yes  NULL
5 playlist   text      latin1_swedish_ci              Yes  NULL
6 description varchar(500) latin1_swedish_ci          Yes  NULL
7 path       varchar(300) latin1_swedish_ci           Yes  NULL
8 genre      varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci            Yes  NULL
```

**This is what my PostMan is showing me**

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Audio uploaded successfully",
    "audio": "http://_/uploads/Uwe/audios/Everything/Bitte .3gp",
    "title": "Bitte ",
    "playlist": "Everything",
    "genre": "Fun",
    "description": "Wie soll man es bewältigen"
}
```

Comment: You really should be using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: Done! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if either of these things will help, I would rather comment but I'm waiting on 50 rep.
Most people (in my experience) use PHP in the object-oriented fashion, and therefore I believe you will find better resources if you follow along with an article [like this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Another thing that will be important is closing the statement, again as shown in that article.
Some languages/libraries give a `stmt.commit()` method, I wonder if closing the statement has a similar effect.  They do this so that you can do batch/bulk inserts and efficiently call the same query a large number of times.

One last thing, you should close the connection in all cases, not just the successful ones so that errors don't crash your database with a connection limit reached error.

It should be easy to convert to OOP syntax, but if I missed something, feel free to comment on this and clarify.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your helpful comments. The article was really gave me some new insights and tried to use their way of solving this problem. Unfortunately nothing has changed. I still get no new database insert... In future I will be more catious about closing the stmt and the connection!! Thx

Comment: Hahaha, just saw your comment.  It happens, if you seriously plan to get into DB work, I would HIGHLY recommend getting comfortable with operating MySQL from a terminal.  One perk of that is you will never have funny issues such as this one.  Another, of course, is that when you run a remote server at AWS or something similar, you do not get a GUI view like you do on the web, so the terminal is your only option.  Best of luck to you in your projects

Comment: I will try and take a look at it! I didnt know it is required for AWS services. That suprises me actually. Soon I have to switch to MongoDB I think and then I will have to work with the terminal for sure. Thank you for your useful comments!:)

Answer (score 0):

Jeeezuz I live up to my username... I didnt know that phpmyadmin only displays 25 rows at a time as default.... So I always looked at the last row and expected to see a new one while it was added to the second page...This kept me busy for a week at least. Maaaan hope you have a good laugh about it and other lost people feel less bad. Keep going!!!